# Remove search option filters jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to set few filters to search with this:

```
$.jgrid = {
 search : {
  caption: "Search...",
  Find: "Find",
  Reset: "Reset",
  odata : ['equal', 'not equal'],
  groupOps: [ { op: "AND", text: "all" }, { op: "OR",  text: "any" } ],
  matchText: " match",
  rulesText: " rules"
 }};
```

But I cannot get it to work. It is still listing all filters with an 'undefined' value on the option value. Any ideas?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [searchoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#colmodel_options) in the with corresponding `colModel` and define `sopt: ['eq','ne']`.